# Can i use Switch from reac-router-dom in a component?

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, react-router-dom

i want to ask if i can use Switch from react-router-dom in a component like this ?  because i am getting nothing

```js
import React from 'react';
//import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from '../_helpers'
import { userActions } from '../_actions';
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll());
    }

    render() {
        const { user, users } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />;
      })}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and indexroutes have this code

```js
import Dashboard from "layouts/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";

var indexRoutes = [{ path: "/", name: "Home", component: Dashboard }];

export default indexRoutes;
```

and to be clear i am using this component HomePage in my private route in my app.JSX like this

```js
 <Router history={history}>
                 <div>
                 <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                 <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                 </div>
</Router>
```

and i call my app in index.js like this :

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss";
import "assets/demo/demo.css";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './_helpers';
import { App } from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Can you try adding a route with the path `*`?

Comment: you said **i am getting nothing** -- you mean when you go to '/' path you cannot see Dashboard component?

Comment: @MohitTilwani yes i get the route to dashboard but i cant see any component

Comment: @LorenzHenk i add this route to my homepage component ?

Comment: You add this in the Router, as last route.

Comment: @LorenzHenk thank you very much for answering i did use this  `<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route path="{prop.path}" key={key} component={prop.component} />;
      })}
    </Switch>
    <Route path="*" component={Dashboard}/>

  </Router>`   and it didnt work

Comment: I think the problem is here: `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />`
Try removing the `exact`-keyword and move this Route below the Login route.